# React server side rendering with lots of concurrant requests

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server-side-rendering

we have changed to razzle for a big application, with a very complex structure and important render time. It works quite well and performant so far, but we are having trouble with lot's of concurrent request, in the sense, that the requests start to queue up instead of being processed right away.

I have done some research and found the CPU intensive process of rendering in node to be the problem, so we tried to make it a little better by adding clustering.

We have tried the following code, that doesn't work though, because razzle seems to already trigger the "listen" method in the backend:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');

if(cluster.isMaster) {
    var numWorkers = require('os').cpus().length;

    console.log('Master cluster setting up ' + numWorkers + ' workers...');

    for(var i = 0; i < numWorkers; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }

    cluster.on('online', function(worker) {
        console.log('Worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' is online');
    });

    cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
        console.log('Worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died with code: ' + code + ', and signal: ' + signal);
        console.log('Starting a new worker');
        cluster.fork();
    });
} else {
    var app = require('../build/server');

    app.listen(3000, function() {
         console.log('Process ' + process.pid + ' is listening to all incoming requests');
    });
}
```

Does any of you have tipps for handling high load websites best?
How do you usually tackle and solve this problem?

Is clustering even the way to go or are child_processes what we should look at?
How do you run your applications with a couple of thousand requests, without having to scale up to 1000 cloud server instances.

Comment: Well clustering seems to the most widely suggested solution for handling such cases. You can look at some of the popular clustering solutions like `pm2` for a more stable and manageable implementation. Also you can try using the latest worker threads to off loads any heavy computation. Lastly, you can diagnose your app for leaks and other memory issues using tools like `n-solid` or `node-clinic`.

Comment: @ShobhitChittora thanks for your reply. We are using the node:alpine docker image as a base, which handles the initialization of the node application.
Do you know of a way to do it there, since we don't use pm2 there.
What do you mean by "latest worker threads"?

Comment: Worker threads just arrived in node v10, and I'm not sure off loading server render threr would help. I was just giving a wild idea.

Comment: With regards to `pm2` usage with docker have a look at http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/docker-pm2-nodejs/#official-supported-docker-image.